# AdBlocker blocking window.location.replace

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, adblock

I have a page which does some Google analytics thing, and I also have window.location.replace() function being called on the page, which is getting blocked by a AdBlocker on Mozilla called BlueHell Firewall, Is there an alternative to Window.Location.Replace() which will help me not get blocked.

Comment: Is your script inline? Or an external script?

Comment: If you are asking about window.location.replace() its inline.

Comment: BluHell is a "fast adblocker". It has no whitelists and no rules other than to block things that look like ads. A js redirect shouldn't be an issue unless your script lives inside a div that looks like an ad unit. COuld that be the case?

Comment: Not the case in my code, inline script is in the HEAD tag

Comment: Does it also block Google analytics?